# How to mock a directly-imported function using Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to verify that my method is correctly invoking another, imported method.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to mock the imported method using Jest.

### Method I want to test

*LandingPageManager.ts*

```
import {getJSON} from './getJSON';

public fetchData(url: string) {
    getJSON(url);
}
```

### Method I want to mock

*getJSON.ts*

```
export function getJSON(url: string) {
    // XHR requests logic 
}
```

### Test method

*LandingPageManager.test.ts*

```
import 'jest';
import {getJSON} from '../../../src/web/getJSON';
import {LandingPageManager} from '../../../src/web/LandingPageManager';

describe('fetchData', () => {
  let manager = new LandingPageManager();
  it('passes the correct URL to getJSON', () => {
    const getJsonSpy = jest.mock('../../../src/web/getJSON', jest.fn());

    manager.fetchData('sampleValue');
    expect(getJsonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sampleValue');

    getJsonSpy.restoreAllMocks();
  });
});
```

### Error I'm getting

```
 jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy
```

I've tried setting up the mock a variety of different ways.  But I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  I feel like this should be possible.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks? Note that you should `jest.mock` *outside* the test spec, otherwise it can't be hoisted and you have to re-import the thing you're testing

Comment: I did... extensively.  It's really unclear from the docs.  I was writing custom test modules and everything.  I finally figured out an answer that I'll update in a minute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer.

Nothing needed to change in the source code (either the imported module or the class under test).

The import needed to change from:

```
import {getJSON} from '../../../src/web/getJSON';
```

to:

```
import * as getJSON from '../../../src/web/getJSON';
```

And then I was able to directly specify the function for spying with:

```
const jsonSpy = jest.spyOn(getJSON, 'getJSON');
```

### Fixed test case

Here's how it all works together now.

*LandingPageManager.test.ts*

```
import 'jest';
// **** 1.) Changed the below line: ****
import * as getJSON from '../../../src/web/getJSON';
import {LandingPageManager} from '../../../src/web/LandingPageManager';

describe('fetchData', () => {
  let manager = new LandingPageManager();
  it('passes the correct URL to getJSON', () => {
    // **** 2.) Can now specify the method for direct mocking ****
    const jsonSpy = jest.spyOn(getJSON, 'getJSON');

    manager.fetchData('sampleValue');
    expect(jsonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sampleValue');

    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
});
```

Comment: There is a typo in the example code. It should be: expect(jsonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sampleValue') and jest.restoreAllMocks()

Comment: Thanks, I made the updates